# How can I create a SSH tunnel to access a remote computer hosting a webserver

Tags: ssh, webserver, vps, tunnel

I'm in the following situation,

I have a VPS with a public static address where I can SSH to it.
I also have a raspberry pi running a webserver on port 80 at home.

My Pi opens a tunnel to the VPS on boot so I can ssh from my VPS to my Pi.

How can I open a tunnel so I can access the webserver on the PI from my browser by typing the URL of my VPS (eg http://myserver.com:8080).

I tried to open a tunnel from the pi with the following command:
`ssh vps -R 8080:localhost:80`

I also tried to open a tunnel from my VPS
`ssh pi -L 8080:pi:80`

Comment: I've also added in the configuration of my VPS in /etc/ssh/sshd_config the following line:
 `GatewayPorts yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the port accessible from outside (`myserver.com:8080`), you need to specify also the remote bind address:

```
ssh vps -R myserver.com:8080:localhost:80
```

or

```
ssh vps -R server_ip:8080:localhost:80
```

That should work for you if you have set up the `GatewayPorts yes`, you don't have anyhow limited forwardings using `PermitOpen` and you have restarted your `sshd` server.

Comment: So from my PI I type

Comment: @BenD so what do you type?

Comment: Sorry I started writing something, I pressed enter by mistake and just saw that. Indeed @Jakuje that works ! thank you for you help :)